# Why React expects me to add setters as useEffects dependencies

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to use an async function inside a useEffect callback.

There is a behavior i don't understand (in my case related to the `throttle` function from lodash).

I don't get what is happing, and how to solve it, here is a sample of the code:

```
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';

const myRequestWrapped = throttle(myRequest, 300);

const [name, setName] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    myRequest(name) // No warning

    myRequestWrapped(name); // React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'myRequestWrapped'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

}, [ name ]);
```

If i add `myRequestWrapped` as a dependency, i have an infinite loop (the effect is triggered continuously).

I guess the `throttle` method works with a timer and it returns a different result at every run so i can understand why the infinite loop.

But i really don't understand why React wants it as a dependency (especially that it works without adding it !).

What is the logic? 
Why `myRequestWrapped` and not `myRequest`?
Should i ignore the warning or do you know a clean way to solve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not React that wants you to add `myRequestWrapped` as a dependency but its `eslint`.

Also you must note that ESLint isn't aware of the programmers intention so it just warns the user if there is a scope of error being made.

Hooks heavily rely on closures and sometimes its difficult to figure out bugs related to closures and that is why eslint prompts if there is a case of a fucntion of variabled used within useEffect that might reflect the updated values.

Of course the check isn't perfect and you could carefully decide whether you need to add a dependency to useEffect or not.

If you see that what you wrote is perfectly correct. You can disable the warning

```
useEffect(() => {
    myRequest(name);

    myRequestWrapped(name);

// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [ name ]);
```

Also you must not that throttle function cannot be used within render of functional componentDirectly as it won't be effective if it sets state as the reference of it will change

The solution here is to `use useCallback` hook. Post that even if you add `myRequestWrapped` as a dependency to `useEffect` you won't be seeing an infinite loop since the function will only be created once as useCallback will memoize and return the same reference of the function on each render.

But again you must be careful about adding dependency to `useCallback`

```
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';


const Comp = () => { 
    const myRequestWrapped = useCallback(throttle(myRequest, 300), []);

    const [name, setName] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        myRequest(name);
        myRequestWrapped(name);

    }, [ name ]);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shubham is right: it's not REACT, but ESLint instead (or TSLint, depending on the Linter you are using).

If I may add, the reason why the Linter suggest you to add `myRequestWrapped` is because of how the closures work in JavaScript.
To let you understand, take this easier example (and I need this because I would need to know what it's inside `myRequestWrapped`:

```
const MyComp = props => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const handleEvent = (e) => {
    console.log(count);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', handleEvent);

    return () => { document.body.removeEventListener('click', handleEvent); }
  }, []);

  return <button onClick={e => setCount(s => s +1)}>Click me</button>
}
```

So, right now, when `MyComp` is mounted, the event listener is added to the `document.body`, and anytime the `click` event is triggered, you call `handleEvent`, which will log `count`.

But, since the event listener is added when the component is mounted, the variable `count` inside `handleEvent` is, and always will be, equal to `0`: that is because the instance of `handleEvent` created when you added the event listener is just one, the one that you associated with the event listener.

Instead, if you would write the `useEffect` like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  document.body.addEventListener('click', handleEvent);

  return () => { document.body.removeEventListener('click', handleEvent); }
}, [handleEevent]);
```

Anytime the `handleEvent` method is updated, also your event listener is updated with the one `handleEvent`, thus when clicking on the `document.body` you will always log the latest `count` value.